# Cookie value is Null in javascript and electron

Tags: javascript, electron

Hello i`m beginner in html.
You can see the cookies in the get function.
However, when called by another method, the cookie value does not exist.

```
exports.get = function getCookie(name) { 
  var value = {
      name: name
  };
  ses.cookies.get(value, function(error, cookies) {
    if (name == "service") {
      alert((cookies[0].value) +"1" ) //alert is normal
      return (cookies[0].value).toString()
    }
  })}

--------------------another file --------------------
 alert(cookie.get('service')); // this alert is abnormal
```

What should I do normally print cookies from other files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies API methods in Electron.js are asynchronous. Below are the ways you can create your utility method to get cookie value.

**Old callback way**

```
exports.get = function getCookie(name, callback) {
  var value = {
    name: name
  };
  ses.cookies.get(value, function(error, cookies) {
    if (name == "service") {
      callback((cookies[0].value).toString());
    }
  });
};

// --------------------another file --------------------
cookie.get('service', function(service) {
  alert(service);
});
```

---

**Promose way**

```
exports.get = function getCookie(name) {
  return new Promoise((resolve, reject) => {
    var value = {
      name: name
    };
    ses.cookies.get(value, function(error, cookies) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
        return;
      }
      if (name == "service") {
        alert((cookies[0].value) +"1" ) //alert is normal
        resolve((cookies[0].value).toString());
      }
    });
  });
};

// --------------------another file --------------------
cookie.get('service')
  .then(function(service) {
    alert(service);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error('ERR:', error);
  });
```